# How to access QML Surface3DSeries from C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

How to access a qml Surface3DSeries object from C++?
I’m having serious problems with the QObject::findChildren() approach. My main.qml declares a Surface3D with objectName “mySurface” and a Surface3DSeries item with objectName: “mySurfaceSeries”, something like this:

```
Surface3D {
       objectName: "mySurface"
       width: parent.width
       height: parent.height

       Surface3DSeries {
            objectName: "mySurfaceSeries"

           ItemModelSurfaceDataProxy {
             [...]
           }
       }
   }
```

After loading the qml in main.cpp, my C++ code calls rootObject->findChildren(). The returned object tree contains an object named “mySurface” but does NOT contain an object named “mySurfaceSeries”. I have no idea why - I thought that every item in qml would be represented in the object tree. There are no obvious errors in the qml, and the Surface3D is displayed properly with data provided by the Surface3DSeries.

The tree's “mySurface” object is not a Q3DSurface (through which I could access the series) but rather a QtDataVisualization::DeclarativeSurface which is not described anywhere that I can find. The DeclarativeSurface class is defined in qtdatavis3d/src/datavisualizationqml2/declarativesurface_p.h and contains a promising method seriesList() - but QtCreator says “No type named ‘DeclarativeSurface’ in namespace ‘QtDataVisualization’”, apparently that file is not in QtCreator’s include-file path.

So I am at a loss right now - how can I access Surface3DSeries from C++?

Thanks!
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It is possible, but not supported and not documented.](https://forum.qt.io/topic/113498/how-to-use-qt-s-declarativesurface-in-my-app)